# Pyplot - How to set labels to multiple data plotted in the same subplot ax

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a dataset with multiple classes of data. They are organized like this: [channel, sample, task]. There are 5 channels, 1024 samples per channel per task and there are 270 tasks. I want 5 plots. One per channel. And I want to label each task in each channel. I just have colors to identify each task in time. But the colors are not related to the tasks.

```
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mat_contents = sio.loadmat('SubA_5chan_3LRF')
info = mat_contents['Info']
labels = mat_contents['LABELS'] 
eegdata = mat_contents['EEGDATA'] # [channels, sample in time, trial]

tam_janela = len(eegdata[0, :, 0])

fig, (ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5) = plt.subplots(nrows = 5, ncols = 1, sharex = False, sharey=True)

for trial in range(10):
  x = np.linspace(0, (tam_janela + tam_janela*trial), (tam_janela + tam_janela*trial) )
  ch1.plot((x[(trial*1024):]), eegdata[0, :, trial])
  ch1.set_ylabel('Channel 1 (V)')

  ch2.plot((x[(trial*1024):]), eegdata[1, :, trial])
  ch2.set_ylabel('Channel 2 (V)')

  ch3.plot((x[(trial*1024):]), eegdata[2, :, trial])
  ch3.set_ylabel('Channel 3 (V)')

  ch4.plot((x[(trial*1024):]), eegdata[3, :, trial])
  ch4.set_ylabel('Channel 4 (V)')

  ch5.plot((x[(trial*1024):]), eegdata[4, :, trial])
  ch5.set_xlabel('Time')
  ch5.set_ylabel('Channel 5 (V)')

plt.suptitle('EEG recordings from Subject A with 5 channels')
plt.show()
```

[This is what I have by now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qrxy.png)

Comment: What do you mean by label? Some text above each colored segment?

Comment: Yes, but I have already got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for trial in range(12):
  x = np.linspace(0, (tam_janela + tam_janela*trial), (tam_janela + tam_janela*trial) )

  if labels[trial] == 1:
    task_label = 'Left Hand'
  elif labels[trial] == 2:
    task_label = 'Right Hand'
  elif labels[trial] == 3:
    task_label = 'Both feet'

  lab, = ch1.plot((x[(trial*1024):]), eegdata[0, :, trial], label = 'Inline label')
  ch1.set_ylabel('Channel 1')
  lab.set_label(task_label)

  ch2.plot((x[(trial*1024):]), eegdata[1, :, trial])
  ch2.set_ylabel('Channel 2')

  ch3.plot((x[(trial*1024):]), eegdata[2, :, trial])
  ch3.set_ylabel('Channel 3')

  ch4.plot((x[(trial*1024):]), eegdata[3, :, trial])
  ch4.set_ylabel('Channel 4')

  ch5.plot((x[(trial*1024):]), eegdata[4, :, trial])
  ch5.set_xlabel('Time')
  ch5.set_ylabel('Channel 5')

ch1.legend(loc='center left', fontsize = 7, ncol = 12)
plt.suptitle('EEG recordings from Subject A with 5 channels (V)')

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[The result I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StxzH.png)